# Android Q - How to get real path of Downloads folder

Tags: android, directory, download, realpath

With Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE I get this uri :

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads
```

How can I convert it to `/storage/emulated/0/Download` - the real path?
I don't want use

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

because is deprecated.

EDIT : I need real path of public location for downloads, because on android Q, this is the folder where should be stored public documents.

Comment: are you using Kotlin or Java?

Comment: I am using java

Comment: try getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDir() (methods on Context) instead of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: thank you, all these methods returns real paths, but from private folder, not from public location, I updated my question.

Comment: `location for downloads, because on android Q, this is the folder where should be stored public documents.` Well there is a Documents directory for that i think.

Comment: `I need real path` No. Not at all. Use the uri itself to create files in it. You should forget about File and FileInputStream.

Comment: Sorry, there is no Documents anymore in Android.Q.

Comment: old games don't understand uris, i must convert between uris and real paths :( I get file descriptor from resolver.openFileDescriptor everywhere where I could replace it. Maybe I should ask "how to convert real path to uri"

Comment: WIth getContentResolver(),openFileDescripter() you dont use a 'real path' but an obtained file uri.

Comment: sorry, I forgot add .detachFd(); at the end

Comment: I will create another question, for constructing uris

Answer (score -1):

Based on the docs, use DCIM/... for the RELATIVE_PATH, where ... is whatever your custom subdirectory would be. So, you would wind up with something like this:

```
  val resolver = context.contentResolver
  val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "CuteKitten001")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "DCIM/PerracoLabs")
  }

  val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)

  resolver.openOutputStream(uri).use {
    // TODO something with the stream
  }
```

Note that since RELATIVE_PATH is new to API Level 29, you would need to use this approach on newer devices and use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() on older ones.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your answer, but I don't see how to get real path of Downloads (what is on Android Q folder where should I store public documents) from Uri.

Comment: Follow this link to find Real_Path:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#RELATIVE_PATH

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. resolver.query(uri, new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH}, null, null, null); returns null for second field, first returns correctly display name. Maybe it works only for files, not for folders :( Tested on Q emulator

Comment: This answer didn't in any way answer the question at all.